# Mongodb C# driver sort by nested attribute

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-.net-driver

How do i use the C# driver to sort by a nested object (from a mapreduce query)

```
{"_id": { "date" : "02/01/2001"} }"

SortBy.Descending("_id")  'Sorts by "_id" descending
SortBy.Descending("???")  'Sorts by "date" descending
```

But Im not sure what to put in value to make this happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you have given, it will not be necessary to specify the nested object since sorting by the `_id` field will functionally sort on the date contained in that field.

You can however reach into nested objects using the [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) when needed.  This would look like:

```
SortBy.Descending("_id.date")
```

Comment: Although this doesn't work in a mapreduce situation it is still the correct way to sort by nested attributes